# openfin to launch external batch process with cmd console minimized

Tags: javascript, batch-file, openfin

I am using below Javascript code to launch external process from openfin on Windows,

```javascript
fin.System.launchExternalProcess({
      path: myApp.bat,
      listener: function (result) { console.log('Launching process: ', result.exitCode); }
    })
    .then(payload => { console.log('process launched') })
    .then(() => { console.log('process is up') })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

where `myApp.bat` is like:

```batch-file
@REM env setup and start java
java ...
```

The process is launched and runs successfully. But there is a visible `cmd.exe` window, which I'd like to be hidden, or at the very least minimized.

I can modify my batch file to use use `javaw.exe` or `start` to get rid of the cmd console,

```batch-file
@REM env setup and start java
javaw 
@REM or
start /min java
exit
```

but `java.exe`/`javaw.exe` will run in a background process and disconnects from `openfin`, and I won't be able to stop the process from `openfin` anymore.

Please help with a solution to run the batch file without a visible `cmd.exe` window, but where `openfin` can still control, (terminate), the process later.

Comment: What are the `@env` and `@or` commands, in your batch files. There should never be a need for just `exit` to be a command at the end of your batch files either. I should also say that nobody should be using `.bat` as a file extension for a script run by `cmd.exe`. Those should use the `.cmd` extension.

Comment: Thanks compo! "env" and "or" are meant to be comments.